# qt widget position

Tags: c++, qt, position

I have a main window with a grid layout and have 8 buttons in 2 rows.

```
 ---------------------
|                     | 
| 1     2     3     4 |
|                     | 
|                     |
| 5     6     7     8 |
|                     |
 ---------------------
```

I'm trying to show a popup dialog next to the button that was clicked. So, I'm trying to get the coordinates of the button in the slot connected to `clicked()` signal.

I have tried

```
QPoint p = btn->pos();
```

and

```
QPoint p = btn->geometry().topLeft();
```

and both are (0, 0) for some reason. How can I obtain the position of the button that was clicked in this slot?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need to map the position of the button relative to the parent window.

[QWidget::mapTo](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapFrom)

> Translates the widget coordinate pos to the coordinate system of
>   parent. The parent must not be 0 and must be a parent of the calling
>   widget.